# How do I find out why I get an error when writing to an Excel cell with VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I'm still fairly new to VBA and struggling with its limitations (and mine!). Here's my code:

```
Sub updateCache(CacheKey As String, CacheValue As Variant)

    Dim DataCacheWorksheet As Worksheet, CacheRange As Range, Found As Variant, RowNum As Integer

    Set DataCacheWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataCache")
    Set CacheRange = DataCacheWorksheet.Range("A1:B999")
    Set Found = CacheRange.Find(What:=CacheKey)
    If Found Is Nothing Then
        RowNum = CacheRange.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        DataCache.Add CacheKey, CacheValue
        On Error Resume Next
        DataCacheWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = CacheKey
        DataCacheWorksheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = CacheValue
    Else
        'Do other things
    End If
End Sub
```

When I step through the code, Excel simply exits the sub at the line `DataCacheWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = CacheKey`, with no error. So, two questions:

1. What's the bug that's preventing the value from being updated?
2. Why does Excel ignore my `On Error` command?

**Edit:** If I run the line in the IDE's "Immediate" box, I get the error "Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error. I get the same error regardless of the value of `CacheKey` (I tried Empty, 1234 and "Hello").

**Edit 2:** If I modify the sub so that `CacheKey` and `CacheValue` are hardcoded and the reference to `DataCache` is removed, **and then I run the sub standalone** it works. So why doesn't it work when called from another function? Is it possible that Excel is locking cells while doing calculations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this applies, but you mentioned you were calling this macro from another function.  If you are calling it from a function, depending on how you are calling it, that would explain your problem. For example, a worksheet function entered into a cell cannot modify another cell on the worksheet.  And the attempt to do so will result in the macro merely exiting at that point, without throwing a VBA error.

How to work around this depends on specifics you have yet to share.  Sometimes, worksheet event code can be useful.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, wasn't about to write an answer, but there are 3 things you should modify in your code:

- `Found As Range` and not `As Variant`
- `RowNum As Long` in case it's a row after ~32K
- To trap errors usually `On Error Resume Next` won't help you, it will just jump one line of code. You need to handle the error situation.

***Modified Code***

```
Sub updateCache(CacheKey As String, CacheValue As Variant)

    Dim DataCacheWorksheet As Worksheet, CacheRange As Range, Found As Range, RowNum As Long ' < use Long instead of Integer

    Set DataCacheWorksheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataCache")
    Set CacheRange = DataCacheWorksheet.Range("A1:B999")
    Set Found = CacheRange.Find(What:=CacheKey)
    If Found Is Nothing Then ' check if not found in cache (*Edit 1)
        RowNum = CacheRange.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

        DataCache.Add CacheKey, CacheValue ' I assume you have a `Dictionary somewhere
'        On Error Resume Next <-- Remove this, not recommended to use
        DataCacheWorksheet.Cells(1, 1).Value = CacheKey
        DataCacheWorksheet.Cells(1, 2).Value = CacheValue
    Else
        'Do other things
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks on `Found` and `RowNum`. I do have a dictionary, declared as a global. THe `On Error Resume Next` is just for debugging. I want to catch the error message, but because the sub just exists I can't do that. `On Error Goto XXXX` does nothing, either.But none of that changes the fundamental issue of the error occuring.

Comment: @MarkBarnes what value are you getting for `RowNum` before exiting ?

Comment: `RowNum` returns 2 at the moment.

Comment: @MarkBarnes A note on global variables: if your code errors out, they get reset. So make sure you re-initialize them before using/testing code that assumes they're already initialized.

Comment: @mark you really should take the advice and remove `On Error Resume Next`.  It doesn't do what you seem to think it does.  It will make debugging harder,  because it tells the code to carry on after an error as if nothing happened.  Removing it won't solve your problem,  but it might help you find the problem.

Comment: @chrisneilsen - the `on error resume next` is added in the hope that I could stop the code on the next line with a breakpoint, and then interrogate `err` to see what the error was. As it stands, I get no error message.

Comment: @mark that's not how you do it.  Instead delete that `On Error...` and let vba break on error (make sure you have your settings on _break on unhandled errors_ )

Comment: @mark further, put a break on the line that causes it to stop, and examine the variables _before_ the error